# Why is my program not recognizing the comparison between two strings in an if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

Here is my code (question listed below):
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExampleCode {

```
/**
 * B. Stephens
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    String secretPhrase = "show me the money";
    boolean notDone = true;

    while (notDone = true){
        System.out.print("Guess the puzzle: ");
        String puzzleGuess = input.nextLine();
        if (puzzleGuess == secretPhrase) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed the puzzle!");
            notDone = false;
        }
    }

} // end main
```

For some reason, the program isn't recognizing when my input (puzzleGuess) is the same as secretPhrase.  It seems like there is no reason the correct input shouldn't end the program.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: What operator is the equality operator? Is it `=` or `==`?

Comment: Don't compare content of Strings using `==`. Use `equals()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use .equals() instead of ==
so, your if-statement should be like this: 
if (puzzleGuess.equals(secretPhrase))

as the String is considered to be an object, and any objects comparison must be performed
using .equals(Object o).

Hope my answer did help :)

Comment: `and any objects comparison must be performed using .equals(Object o).` Phrased like that, what you're saying is false.

Comment: Hi Sotirios Delimanolis :)
can you please tell me why is it false?
I always compare objects (strings or from any other class) using .equals()

Comment: `must` is the issue. It always depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: okay, got your point :)

Answer (score 0):

because you need to use the `.equals` method

```
if (puzzleGuess.equals(secretPhrase)) {
    System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed the puzzle!");
    notDone = false;
}
```

Java Strings are interned so `==` can sometimes work.

```
public class InternedDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "hello world";
        String s2 = "hello world";
        String s3 = new String("hello world");

        System.out.println(s1 == s2); // true
        System.out.println(s1 == s3); // false
        System.out.println(s2 == s3); // false

       System.out.println(s1.equals(s3)); // true
       System.out.println(s2.equals(s3)); // true
   }
}
```

Comment: String *Literals* are interned. Dynamically created Strings are only interned if done so explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't compare strings using `==`. Use `secretPhrase.equals(puzzleGuess)`. `==` is just checking if both strings are the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Use .equals() to compare to string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

String secretPhrase = "show me the money";
boolean notDone = true;

while (notDone){
    System.out.print("Guess the puzzle: ");
    String puzzleGuess = input.nextLine();
    if (puzzleGuess.equals(secretPhrase)) {
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed the puzzle!");
    secretPhrase=null;
        notDone = false;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: `while (notDone = true)` ?

Answer (score 0):

== cannot be used to compare Strings. For non-primitives, == determines whether they are the same object. To see whether the two strings have the same value, instead use .equals():

```
String str1 = new String("foo");
String str2 = str1;
String str3 = new String("foo");
String str4 = new String("bar");
System.out.println(str3 == str3); //true
System.out.println(str1 == str2); //true
System.out.println(str1 == str3); //FALSE!
System.out.println(str1.equals(str3)); //true!
System.out.println(str1 == str4); //false
System.out.println(str1.equals(str4)); //false
```

Comment: == can be used to compare Strings, or any other Object for that matter. It is reference equality vs actual equality.